# The bringer of change - I'll make you miss your Ex!

Tags: wordplay

*I proceed with a pastry,

get a grocer's from a gambol,

a persona from a pixie,

add pressure when you practice,

bawl about the balm,

bisect from below,

get chairs from consumption,

dispossess the duck,

dirty the diesel,

drool in a ditch,

find room for a rate,

flesh from the family,

fluster a fish,

glower from a garment,

have contempt for a callus,

insult illumination,

jolt a jackal's joint,

kill off the comedy,

make a superficial saint,

make accurate the ardin,

or firm the furniture,

make raw the rock,

produce tulle from the type,

or an abarka from an adze,

mess up the medicine,

pass round the rodent,

post part of the pelvis,

precipitate the present,

pull a rock from the ring,

puncture the parasite,

secure the subterfuge,

submerge the stain,

show talented from terminated,

spout about the summit,

tighten the team,

turn on a tack,

wear at the waterside,

and conclude at the cover.*

**Question:** Who or what am I?

Comment: Alliteration? :o

Comment: I feel like we'll need to find an ordering since the lines are alphabetical...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I have so far:

> The first word on each line is made by adding a leading s to the second. Applying this to the title means you are: Sex!
>  I proceed with a pastry, - Start with a tart
>  get a grocer's from a gambol, -  get a shop from a hop
>  a persona from a pixie, - self from elf
>  add pressure when you practice - strain when you train
>  bawl about the balm - scream about the cream
>  bisect from below, - sunder from under
>  get chairs from consumption, - seats from eat
>  dispossess the duck - steal the teal
>  dirty the diesel,  - soil the oil
>  drool in a ditch, - spit in a pit
>  find room for a rate, - space for a pace
>  flesh from the family, - Skin from kin
>  fluster a fish, - shake a hake
>  glower from a garment, - scowl from a cowl
>  have contempt for a callus, - have scorn for a  corn
>  insult illumination, - slight light
>  jolt a jackal's joint, - shock the hock
>  kill off the comedy, - slaughter  the laughter
>  make a superficial saint, - make a shallow hallow
>  make accurate the ardin, - sharp the harp
>  or firm the furniture, - stable the table
>  make raw the rock, - sore the ore
>  produce tulle from the type, - produce silk from the ilk
>  or an abarka from an adze, - shoe from a hoe
>  mess up the medicine, - spill the pill?
>  pass round the rodent, - share the hare (pretty sure this is right,though hares are lagomorphs, not rodents)
>  post part of the pelvis, - ship the hip
>  precipitate the present, - snow the now
>  pull a rock from the ring, - stone from the tone
>  puncture the parasite, - stick the tick
>  secure the subterfuge, - strap the trap
>  submerge the stain, - sink the ink
>  show talented from terminated - show skilled from the killed
>  spout about the summit, - speak about the peak
>  tighten the team, - screw the crew
>  turn on a tack, - spin on a pin
>  wear at the waterside - sport at the port
>  and conclude at the cover. - stop at the top

Comment: Close enough! I had "seating" rather than "seat" and the actual answer I was looking for was the one posted by Toby, but you've found all the words. (Sorry about the hare!)

Answer (score 3):

cant find a fit for all (yet!??) but the answer may be

---

> the letter S

eg. I proceed with a pastry

> Start / tart

eg. a persona from a pixie

> Self / elf

Comment: apologies - not sure how to spoiler-ise a big block of text with more answers...

Comment: Use <br> to create a newline in a spoiler.

Comment: +1 for finding the correct answer, but Irishpanda gets the tick for the complete answer.

Comment: no worries Gordon K - Well done to IrishPanda! thanks to dpwilson for the tutorial too ;-)